# LLVM TargetRegistry finds no targets

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, vcpkg, llvm-c++-api

I am trying to JIT some llvm IR, but my c++ code can't find any targets.
Here is the c++ code:

```cpp
#include <llvm/MC/TargetRegistry.h>
#include <llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h>

int main() {
    llvm::InitializeAllTargets();
    llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos();
    llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs();

    for (const llvm::Target& target : llvm::TargetRegistry::targets()) {
        std::cout << "Target Name: " << target.getName() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The included llc.exe tool can find them :

[image: llc.exe result]

I installed llvm using vcpkg, and I am running windows 11.

I tried both release and debug, neither works.

Thanks